# A space efficient data structure to store and look-up through a large set of (uniformly distributed) Integers

Tags: java, memory-management, data-structures, hashcode

I'm required to hold, in memory, and look-up through one million uniformly distributed integers.
My workload is extremely look-up intensive.
My current implementation uses a HashSet (Java). I see good look-up performance, but the memory usage is not ideal (dozens of MB).
**Could you think of a more efficient (memory) data structure?**
*Edit: The solution will need to support a small amount additions to the data stracture.*

**Background:**
The Integers problem stated above is a simplification of the following problem:
I have a set of one million Strings (my "Dictionary"), and I want to tell whether the Dictionary contains a given string, or not.
The Dictionary is too large to fit in memory, so I'm willing to sacrifice a tiny bit of accuracy to reduce memory footprint. I'll do that by switching to a Dictionary containing each String's Hashcode value (integer), instead of the actual chars. I'm Assuming that the chance of a collision, per string, is only `1M/2^32`.

Comment: Could be a job for a [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)?

Comment: do you need an `insert` operation or is the dictionary built once and never modified any more during the lookups ?

Comment: @Gareth Rees: why don't you post that as an answer so it can be upvoted?

Comment: @Andre - Thank you for being a careful reader. I did made the mistake of not explicitly stating that The solution will need to support a small amount additions to the data structure.

Answer (score 13):

While Jon Skeet's answer gives good savings for a small investment, I think you can do better. Since your numbers are fairly even distributed, you can use an interpolating search for faster lookups (roughly O(log log N) instead of O(log N)). For a million items, you can probably plan on around 4 comparisons instead of around 20.

If you want to do just a little more work to cut the memory (roughly) in half again, you could build it as a two-level lookup table, basically a sort of simple version of a trie.

[image]

You'd break your (presumably) 32-bit integer into two 16-bit pieces. You'd use the first 16 bits as an index into the first level of the lookup table. At this level, you'd have 65536 pointers, one for each possible 16-bit value for that part of your integer. That would take you to the second level of the table. For this part, we'd do a binary or interpolation search between the chosen pointer, and the next one up -- i.e., all the values in the second level that had that same value in the first 16 bits.

When we look in the second table, however, we already know 16 bits of the value -- so instead of storing all 32 bits of the value, we only have to store the *other* 16 bits of the value.

That means instead of the second level occupying 4 megabytes, we've reduced it to 2 megabytes. Along with that we need the first level table, but it's only 65536x4=256K bytes.

This will almost certainly improve speed over a binary search of the entire data set. In the worst case (using a binary search for the second level) we could have as many as 17 comparisons (1 + log<sub>2</sub> 65536). The average will be better than that though -- since we have only a million items, there can only be an average of 1_000_000/65536 = ~15 items in each second-level "partition", giving approximately 1 + log<sub>2</sub>(16) = 5 comparisons. Using an interpolating search at the second level might reduce that a little further, but when you're only starting with 5 comparisons, you don't have much room left for really dramatic improvements. Given an average of only ~15 items at the second level, the type of search you use won't make much difference -- even a linear search is going to be pretty fast.

Of course, if you wanted to you could go a step further and use a 4-level table instead (one for each byte in the integer). It may be open to question, however, whether that would save you enough more to be worth the trouble. At least right off, my immediate guess is that you'd be doing a fair amount of extra work for fairly minimal savings (just storing the final bytes of the million integers obviously occupies 1 megabyte, and three levels of table leading to that would clearly occupy a fair amount more, so you'd double the number of levels to save something like half a megabyte. If you're in a situation where saving just a little more would make a big difference, go for it -- but otherwise, I doubt whether the return will justify the extra investment.

Comment: nice optimization indeed. I guess it will come in handy once I'll have one/two orders of magnitude more data.

Comment: Are there a sample implementation?

Comment: @Horcrux7: I Wrote up a proof of concept at the time to be sure it'd work before posting it. I could look for that when I get home tonight (if I remember), but six years later there's a good chance I've tossed it.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I have try to implements it in the PagedIntSet and host it at [LargeIntegerSet](https://github.com/Horcrux7/LargeIntegerSet). If you see options for a more efficient version then contribute it please.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you could just keep a sorted `int[]` and then do a binary search. With a million values, that's ~20 comparisons to get to any value - would that be fast enough?

Comment: But this should have the same memory footprint as a HashSet, no?

Comment: @user949300: No, because a `HashSet` will have to allocate an `Integer` object for each value (massive difference in size!), *and* it won't be densely populated like I'm suggesting, *and* it will have to keep the hash code for each value *and* it will have an `Entry` object for each value (which will contain the hash code, of course, so that's somewhat double counting). All of this busts the cache more as well as taking more memory, of course.

Comment: @user949300 No, the HashSet is backed by a HashMap and has quite a few empty cells, depending on the actual values you store.

Comment: Some of the smaller Integers are already cached (no memory alloc) but yes, it would be allocating a bunch of the large ones.  So your idea has a roughly 4X space savings, not even counting the Entry object, which I forgot about.  I'm apparently focusing too much on my fantasy baseball team this afternoon.  :-)

Comment: `HashSet` is a massive memory hog compared to an `int[]`.

Comment: @Jon: This does sound something I'll be able to live (leave :) with.
I didn't explicitly say that I'll need to handle some additions as well. I guess that I can hold these additions on the side, merging them (recreating the ints array) every once in a while... Any better idea?
Thx!

Comment: @GiliNachum: Nope, that sounds like the best you're likely to manage. As you say, keep a large `int[]` and a `HashSet<Integer>` - only merge the set into the array when it starts getting large.

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to accept a small chance of a false positive in return for a large reduction in memory usage, then a [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) may be just what you need.

A Bloom filter consists of *k* hash functions and a table of *n* bits, initially empty. To add an item to the table, feed it to each of the *k* hash functions (getting a number between 0 and *n*−1) and set the corresponding bit. To check if an item is in the table, feed it to each of the *k* hash functions and see if all corresponding *k* bits are set.

A Bloom filter with a 1% false positive rate requires about 10 bits per item; the false positive rate decreases rapidly as you add more bits per item.

[Here's an open-source implementation in Java.](https://github.com/magnuss/java-bloomfilter)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at a [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) The one used in Lucene is even faster as the standard Java implementation since it neglects some standard boundary checks.

Comment: My first response wqas a Bitset, but then realized that since hashCodes go up to 2^31 the size could be huge, if both very low values (near 0) and large (near MAXINT) were included.  Alsom, you'd need two Bitsets, one for the positives, one for the negatives

Comment: @user949300 if you need two BitSets then each will hold half the bits, and to store 2^32 bits requires 2^29 bytes - large but not impossible. I think the Bloom Filter from a different answer would be a better solution, since it can achieve lower memory usage with a higher rejection of false positives.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you might reconsider original problem (having efficient word list), rather than trying to optimize the "optimalization".

I would suggest looking into Radix tree/Trie.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree
or
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

You are basically storing some kind of tree with prefixes of strings, branching every time there is a choice in dictionary. It has some interesting side effects (allows filtering on prefixes very efficiently), can save some memory for strings with longer common prefixes and is reasonably fast.

[image: Radix tree example]

Some example implementations:

https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-stempel/org/egothor/stemmer/Trie.html

https://github.com/rkapsi/patricia-trie

https://github.com/npgall/concurrent-trees

There is interesting comparison of various implementations here, with bigger focus on performance rather than memory usage, but it can be still helpful

http://bhavin.directi.com/to-trie-or-not-to-trie-a-comparison-of-efficient-data-structures/

Answer (score 1):

There are some Java implementation of Sets for Integers with reduced memory consumption in the Github project [LargeIntegerSet](https://github.com/Horcrux7/LargeIntegerSet).

Answer (score 0):

There are some `IntHashSet` implementations for primitives available.

Quick googling got me [this one](https://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/XML/saxonb/net/sf/saxon/sort/IntHashSet.java.htm).  There is also an apache [open source] implementation of [IntHashSet](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/util/collections/IntHashSet.html). I'd prefer the apache implementation, though it has some overhead [it is implemented as a [IntToIntMap](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/util/collections/IntToIntMap.html)]