# Does std::unordered_map::erase actually perform dynamic deallocation?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, dynamic-memory-allocation

It isn't difficult to find information on the big-O time behavior of stl container operations. However, we operate in a hard real-time environment, and I'm having a lot more trouble finding information on their heap memory usage behavior.

In particular I had a developer come to me asking about std::unordered_map. We're allowed to be non-realtime at startup, so he was hoping to perform a .reserve() at startup time. However, he's finding he gets overruns at runtime. The operations he uses are lookups, insertions, and deletions with .erase().

I'm a little worried about that .reserve() actually preventing later runtime memory allocations (I don't really understand the explanation of what it does wrt to heap usage), but .erase() in particular I don't see any guarantee whatsoever that it won't be asking the heap for a dynamic deallocation when called.

So the question is what's the specified heap interactions (if any) for std::unordered_map::erase, and if it actually does deallocations, if there's some kind of trick that can be used to avoid them?

Comment: I believe this is implementation defined. I would check the source code for whatever version of STL you're using to confirm your suspicions

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso - IMHO, "implementation defined" is roughly equivalent to "undefined", and that would be an OK as an answer to the question, if true. We have to support the software we deliver for decades, so something a compiler vendor is free to make non-realtime on us without notice is not a good solution for us, and I'd like to know that going in.

Comment: @T.E.D.: "*However, we operate in a hard real-time environment*" Then why are you trying to use the standard library containers? They aren't made for that sort of thing.

Comment: @NicolBolas - We do OK with simple ones like std::string, std::vector, std::map, etc. with the caveat that they are initialized at startup (when we can be non-realtime), and then only read from thereafter (including nuances like not using the array operator on maps if you're not sure its in there). As for doing something as complex as this dev wants to do, yeah I share your suspicion. But I was asked the question and didn't know for certain its a problem, so I'm asking.

Comment: maybe you can provide a custom allocator.

Comment: @appleapple -True. I have other things to do though, so that's gonna be a "no" for the poor dev.

Comment: @T.E.D. Last time I did work in a "real time" environment (games), we used our own custom containers instead of STL because STL kept allocating at times we didn't like.

Comment: `"implementation defined" is roughly equivalent to "undefined"`  not quite. Implementation-defined means it is a documented behaviour for your compiler and  toolchain (not necessary for exact target platform or instruction set, that's platform-defined). Undefined behavior is not documented at all and may depend on circumstances or implementation quirks, on order of compilation,etc. Undetermined is a random, dependant on runtime factors which may be random as well.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie - You're missing my point. They are equivalent *to me* because we have to maintain the same software across decades and multiple compilers. If its not language-defined, I can't count on the behavior, no matter what the compiler du jour is currently doing.

Comment: @T.E.D. I know that pain, yeah, I'm in same situation. After going down there is certain stage where it's no longer an option. Some platforms have own implementation of memory access so even a home-made container get affected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard doesn't specify container allocation patterns per-se. These are effectively derived from iterator/reference invalidation rules. For example, `vector::insert` only invalidates all references if the number of elements inserted causes the size of the container to exceed its capacity. Which means reallocation happened.

By contrast, the only operations on `unordered_map` which invalidates references are those which actually remove that particular element. Even a rehash (which likely allocates memory) does not invalidate references (this is why `reserve` changes nothing).

This means that each element must be stored separately from the hash table itself. They are individual nodes (which is why it has a `node_type` extraction interface), and must be able to be allocated and deallocated individually.

So it is reasonable to assume that each insertion or erasure represents at least one allocation/deallocation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're all right with nodes continuing to consume memory, even after they've been removed from the container, you could pretty easily write an Allocator class that basically made deallocation a NOP.

Quite a few real-time systems basically allocate all the memory they're going to use up-front, then once they've finished initialization they neither allocate nor release memory. This would allow you to do pretty much the same thing with an unordered_map.

That said, I'm somewhat skeptical about the benefit in this case. The main strength of unordered_map is supporting insertion and deletion that are usually fast. If you're not going to be doing insertion at runtime, chances are pretty good that it's not a particularly great choice.

If it's a collection that's mostly filled during initialization, then used mostly as-is, with a few items being "removed", but no more being inserted after you finish initialization, you're likely to be better off with a simple sorted array and an interpolating search (or, if the data is distributed *extremely* unpredictably, maybe a binary search--but an interpolating search is usually better). In this case, I'd handle removal by simply adding a boolean to each item saying whether that item is valid or not. Erase by setting that value to false. If you find such a value during a search, you basically just ignore it.

Comment: We're *generally* OK with using extra memory in exchange for not doing allocations at runtime. However, when our application shuts down it needs to deallocate/free all its resources, and we don't have an OS with heavy processes that ensures that, so code has to do it. So we can't just completely lose track of what's allocated.

Comment: Also, I'm kind of asking about out-of-the-box behavior here. I could certainly whip up a real-time allocator myself. Real time heaps exist. However, I'm not looking to take on extra coding work, just answer a dev's question.

Comment: I think your last para has the right of it. The dev's main issue is that the "key" they want to search on is a 16-bit int, and they don't want to just allocate a huge sparse array. So they wanted a hashed search to be happening.

Comment: @T.E.D.: For 16-bit integers as keys, I'd at least consider breaking it into two bytes, and using a two-level table like I described in [an old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9754470/179910).